# How can all modules all log to root logger?

Tags: python, logging

I'm using `dictConfig` (loaded from a file), and I'd like to have everything default to the handlers I set on the root logger.  So if in `my.module` I have

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.debug("debug msg")
logger.info("info msg")
```

without specifying anything special about `my.module` in my logging configuration, the debug and info should be handled per the configurations I set on the root logger.  Everything I've read suggests this should just work.  From https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial :

> Child loggers propagate messages up to the handlers associated with their ancestor loggers. Because of this, it is unnecessary to define and configure handlers for all the loggers an application uses. It is sufficient to configure handlers for a top-level logger and create child loggers as needed. (You can, however, turn off propagation by setting the propagate attribute of a logger to False.)

However, I've found this doesn't work unless my `dictConfig` explicitly lists every single logger.  If I don't do that, none of my configuration seems to take effect.  (You can compare the [master](https://github.com/squito/python_logging_demo/blob/master/resources/logging.yaml) vs. [broken](https://github.com/squito/python_logging_demo/blob/broken/resources/logging.yaml) branches of my demo project.)

I load the dictConfig from a yaml file with

```py
  with open("resources/logging.yaml") as f:
    loggingConfig = yaml.safe_load(f)
  logging.config.dictConfig(loggingConfig)
```

I don't really understand what is different in the two situations -- I've looked at things like the level, the effectiveLevel, the parent, the handlers, etc. and they seem the same in the two situations.  I'm setting `propagate=True`, but in fact without that snippet, the loggers still have `propagate=True`.  I'd also be OK with a solution that just has me set some magical property on each logger I create, eg.

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setMagicalPropertyHere()
```

(btw I'm coming at this with a log4j mentality, which could explain my confusion)

Comment: Maybe it's just a timing issue? Are the child loggers being created before the master is initialized?

Comment: @MarkRansom hmm, I am loading the configuration after the loggers are defined.  I thought it had to be that way, since I only load the configuration in my `__main__` section, which needs to be at the end.  Maybe it means I need to move those `__main__` sections out of files with "regular" code?

Comment: Indeed, that was it!  You should post an answer so I can accept it.  You can reference this: https://github.com/squito/python_logging_demo/commit/9d37466570d4879f0581fa05430bec1d3ab9b29c.  (If I can, I'll even edit your answer for you)